# React.js terminal messages and error page theme changed when create new project with npx create-react-app, now showing asset static/js/bundle.js

Tags: reactjs

my question is not about the code, it is about changes in the page errors in the react, such as the page theme, new terminal information, etc


Yesterday I created a new react.js project with npx but it was not as usual, the error page is different and in the terminal, it shows other things that were not like before.
Has this happened to anyone else?
How can it be fixed?

here is the picture of the new project that was created yesterday :
[image: error page in new project]

[image: terminal in new project]

and here is the picture of the project that I created about 3 months ago and it's different
[image: old project error page]

Comment: Can you please share the code, also please take screenshots, using `windows` + `shift` + `s`

Answer (score 1):

This webpack bundling messages comes default with the latest version of `react-scripts`, ie, `5.0.0`.

Nothing to worry about it but if you really want to avoid the terminal messages consider downgrading `react-scripts` to a lower version.

Downgrading to version `4.0.3` seems to fix the issue.

```
npm install react-scripts@4.0.3
```

or

```
yarn add react-scripts@4.0.3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How about the error screen? No need to fix it? Like page theme changes and ...

Comment: @Hadi Content seems to be the same. Never bothered to change it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the code, but my guess is that you misspelled `default` with `ult`, try to change it

Comment: Thank you for your time, my question is not about the code, it is about changes in the page errors in the react, such as the page theme, new terminal information, etc.